# Implementation of Map<string, string> in C

Tags: c, data-structures

For some reason, I have to implement this myself , and can not use libs.
To make it map fast, firstly, I map the key to an integer, and use that integer as an internal key. Then I implement the Map, which gives me the mapping function. However, when I use the string key to compute the internal integer key, sometimes I get the same integer from different string. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot avoid this. There are more possible strings than integers, therefore hash collisions are imminent. Read up on hashmaps - it's a data structure that explicitly takes collisions into account and works around them.

Answer (score 2):

A map data structure and "collision" cannot be separated. the way you started your implementation seems fine, here's how you should handle collisions :

**Adding a new entry into the map**

1. calculate `hashcode` for `key`
2. compute `index` from hashcode (more or less `index` = `hashcode value` % `size of keyset`)
3. if `keyset[index]` is not null

   1. if keyset[index] != key (ie. for strings, use strcmp) increment `index` modulus `size of keyset`, then goto 3
4. put `value` into `entryset[index]`

**Getting a value from the map**

1. calculate `hashcode` for `key`
2. compute `index` from hashcode (more or less `index` = `hashcode value` % `size of keyset`)
3. if `keyset[index]` is not null

   1. if keyset[index] != key (ie. for strings, use strcmp) increment `index` modulus `size of keyset`, then goto 3
4. if `keyset[index]` is null return null
5. return `entryset[index]`

**Deleting an entry from the map**

1. calculate `hashcode` for `key`
2. compute `index` from hashcode (more or less `index` = `hashcode value` % `size of keyset`)
3. if `keyset[index]` is not null

   1. if keyset[index] != key (ie. for strings, use strcmp) increment `index` modulus `size of keyset`, then goto 3
4. set `keyset[index]` and `entryset[index]` to null

As you can see, you can put step 1 to 3 into a function `int findIndexFromKey(Map *map, char *key);` and most of the work is done

** **EDIT** **

Of course, you also have to check if your map is not full before (or while) adding a new entry, otherwise you'll just loop undefinitely.

Comment: Your loop in "adding a new entry" will never terminate if the same key has already been added.

Comment: true, I'm fixing it now. Though the general idea is there

Comment: Your deletion function is also incorrect - if you add `key1` followed by `key2` which have the same hash, then delete `key1`, `key2` is lost (won't be found by the `get` function).

Answer (score 1):

This is what is known as a collisions, but the simplest is to make each bucket in your Hashmap a list of items with the same hash.  Then on a *get* all you have to do is iterate through the list until you find the item you are looking for.